# When is each meaning of shelled used?

Tags: meaning

Bing says by citing an Oxford dictionary

> shelled (adjective)

> 1. having a protective outer case or covering:
>    "crabs and other shelled creatures" · "hard-shelled pistachios"

> 2. having the outer case or covering removed:
>    "shelled peas" · "shelled prawns"

The two meanings are opposite to each other. How can I tell which meaning is in use in any case?

If I wanfmt to say hazelnuts just picked from its plants, with shell on, shall I call them raw shelled hazelnuts?

Answer (score 3):

This is a well-known example, and there aren't hard rules that would satisfy a mathematician or programmer.  Sorry but English is a natural language.

Generally you add an adjective to add meaning. The form with an adjective probably means the type that differs from the normal.

Most animals don't have shells, so "shelled animals" probably means those that are different from the normal.  It means animals with shells.

Most nuts have shells, so "shelled nuts" probably means those that have had their shells removed.

Hard-shelled describes a type of shell, so it can't mean "shell removed", and so hard-shelled pistachios must mean pistachios with a hard shell.

Your hazelnuts normally have a shell. So "Raw shelled hazelnuts" would mean "shell removed".  You should say something like Raw hazelnuts in their shells, or "Hazelnuts in Shell" (since that implies they are raw)

The same reasoning can be applied to other words which can mean either "with X added" or "with X removed", such as "dusted" or "pitted". A layer of dust forms naturally on the shelf, so if the shelf is "dusted" it probably means "with dust removed".  Whereas cakes don't naturally get a layer of icing sugar, so if the cakes are "dusted" (with sugar) it means "with (sugar) dust added".

Comment: I always look for jars of olives where the label says 'pitted'.